# How to click night view photos from mobile phone?

Tags: photography-basics, night-photography

I find it difficult to click a photo of a hill-station from its height at night, because its lights are not captured well and also gets blurred if zoom. So how to click in mobile?

I want the photo similar to the view i see through my eyes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do much. Nearly all phone cameras cannot zoom. The "zoom" you're talking of is purely software and it's virtually the same as zooming in on a picture in a photo viewer application. You can imagine that such zoom does not resolve more detail when zooming in: you are just enlarging existing pixels. Hence why you're mentioning the picture gets blurred.
You could try buying an add-on lens for your phone. Such add-on lenses extend the focal length, giving you optical "zoom" ('zoom' means a lens has a range of focal lengths. In reality you merely change the fixed focal length, so it is not real zoom).

Still, phone cameras just don't do well at low-light conditions.

Comment: WIth some phone models, supporting it with a tripod and remote release could help - more if there is a mode for this kind of setup!

Comment: Is it a true zoom lens, or *another camera with another lens* with a longer focal length?

Comment: @MichaelC that's why I put quotation marks around the word zoom. It's not really a zoom lens by any definition, but one could add and remove the second lens, effectively creating the effect of a two-position zoom lens. Take it with a grain of salt :)

Comment: @Tetsujin The iPhone 11 Pro has three cameras with a "wide" lens, a "standard" lens, and a "long" lens. The "long" lens is not a zoom lens any more than a telephoto prime lens for an ILC is a "zoom" lens, which it is not. What the camera interpolates digitally doesn't alter the properties of the lenses used to collect the data it uses.

Comment: I'm no longer going to reply to anything you say. If I need nits picking, I'll see a doctor.

Comment: Technically, nits are lice eggs, so to have them picked you will will want a personal groomer (or a pet chimpanzee), not a doctor. Hope his helps!

Answer (score 4):

*There is not a camera made that will perform as well as the human eye/brain.*

Get a camera app for your phone that will allow you to change the shutter speed and iso manually ( I use procam 6 but i have several that are made for low light night shots as well )  and **use a tripod**.

Also research HDR photography, this is when you take several shots of the same scene at different exposures and then combine them all together in post production. This allows you to get the proper exposure for the shadows in some shots and the highlights in other shots. After you combine them in post then you have a better representation of the dynamic range of the scene you are photographing then would be possible with just a one a shot exposure.

*Night photography is difficult, the dynamic range is far to wide for a camera to capture all the detail that your eye/brain see's . **Your brain is very good at it**.*

**Take a class on photography** it will benefit you to have a solid understanding of light and how cameras see it ( *even if you are only using a phone camera*. )